# iOS11 Drag behavior not working in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, drag-and-drop, ios11

I am facing a problem while developing Drag&Drop iOS11 feature to allow send and receive data between apps.

In the tableView of a view controller, with it's `dragDelegate` and `dropDelegate` assigned on `viewDidLoad` to the view controller itself, I implement the

`- (NSArray<UIDragItem *> *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView itemsForBeginningDragSession:(id<UIDragSession>)session atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method, but it is never being called.

The drop behavior is working correctly and the table view can consume items from other apps such Photos or Notes. But when I tap a table view row for a couple of seconds, nothing happens. The lift animation doesn't occur and the drag delegate isn't fired.

Any thoughts? Am I missing anything required?

Answer (score 0):

On iPhone, besides setting the `dragDelegate` you must also set `dragInteractionEnabled` on the `UITableView` to true. On iPad, this property is set to true by default.

Answer (score -1):

Please try below delegate methods for re-ordering of cell.

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```

Implement the following UITableView datasource method in your project.

```
 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{
[dataArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row withObjectAtIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Nothing of this throw the itemsForBeginningDragSession delegate method... Thanks Pankaj